# Eigen Beamforming: Explanation

Tags: beamforming, mimo, channel-estimation, adaptive-beamforming

It's been a few days that I have been searching the term eigen beamforming, but still haven't get any satisfactory literature reference. It would be great if you could give any details or point to any literature regarding the topic **eigen beamforming**.

Furthermore, one more specific question, is precoding essential for eigen beamforming? Without precoding will eigen beamforming exist?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "eigenbeamforming"?

Comment: Hi Aragorn, you will need to refer us to a reference for that word, because it's not a fixed term as far as I'm aware, and I could imagine a few slightly and slightly more different things it *could* mean. So, probably, you will have to pick a specific publication that introduces the term, and ask us to explain this specific publication's definition – but when doing so, please make sure to describe what you *do* understand, and what you need help with, because as written, your question would be a bit broad.